# How can I switch to Classic Mode on Monkey Island 2 Special Edition?

Tags: monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge-se

How can I do it on the different platforms?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### iPhone/iPad

Slide with 2 fingers (right to left) and the same to have back the Enhanced Version.

### Xbox 360

Press the <kbd>Back</kbd> button on your controller.

### PC

Press <kbd>F1</kbd>, or press <kbd>Page Up</kbd> for Classic Mode and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> for Enhanced Version.

### PlayStation 3

Press <kbd>Select</kbd> button

### Mac

Press <kbd>0</kbd>

Comment: Maybe we should just combine them in one answer :)

Comment: Good call, my contribution is now deleted. :)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F10</kbd> works to toggle between modes on PC.

Answer (score 0):

On the PC version, press F1, or press Page Up for Classic Mode and Page Down for Enhanced.

On iPhone, slide with two fingers right to left.

Answer (score 0):

On PS3 you just have to press SELECT